# Is $\bar{h}$ a typo of $h$ in Functional Equivariance and Formal Invariance in Lehmann's TPE?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, definition

On [page 161 of Lehmann and Casella's Theory of Point Estimation](http://books.google.com/books?id=9St7DCbu9AUC&lpg=PA223&ots=MCCtt8-jIF&dq=Measurement%20Equivariance%20formal%20invariance&pg=PA161#v=onepage&q&f=false), they introduce Functional Equivariance and Formal Invariance.

$\bar{h}$ appears in two places:

- in "Functional Equivariance":

  > $\phi[\delta(X)]$as the estimator of $\phi[\bar{h}(\theta)]$
- in "Formal Invariance": equation (2.16)

I didn't find the definition of $\bar{h}$, so I was wondering if  $\bar{h}$ is a typo of $h$? Or how is it defined? Thanks and regards!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that $\bar{h}$ is not previously defined? I do not have this edition but I do have Lehman's earlier *Theory of Point Estimation,* wherein $\bar{h}$ is the transformation on the distributional parameters induced by the transformation $h$ on the sample space: "If $gX$ has the distribution $P_{\theta'}$, then $\theta' = \bar{g}\theta$ is a function which maps $\Omega$ into $\Omega$ ... the transformations $\bar{g}$ then also form a group ... ." It is likely the same, or a comparable, definition appears on p. 160 of your edition.

Comment: @whuber:Thanks! on p160, I saw given $g$ that maps the sample $X$ from a value to another value, $\bar{g}$ is a mapping that maps the parameter $\theta$ from a value to another value. On the other hand, $h$ here maps $\theta$ from a value to another value, and $\bar{h}$ still maps the parameter $\theta$ from a value to another value. Isn't it wrong? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you may be correct, but the interpretation comes down to the definition of $h$, which likely also appears on the preceding page.

Comment: @whuber: I think $h$ is just an arbitrary function of $\theta$, and $h(\theta)$ is what to be estimated.